# send_push_message() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'token', 'title', 'message', and 'extra'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I keep getting this error: send_push_message() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'token', 'title', 'message', and 'extra', what can i do?

```
def receive_request(request, self):
    self.token = request.data['token']
    self.title = request.data['title']
    self.message = request.data['message']
    self.extra = request.data['extra']

@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def send_push_message(self, token, title, message, extra):
    token =  self.token   
    title = self.title 
    message = self.message 
    extra = self.extra
    #it continues from here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django Rest Framework, function based views should accept a `request` as the first argument and then any other arguments need to be defined by regular expression capture in the url definition for the view. See this doc for more: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views

It looks like the data you're getting comes from the request body. Note that to pass arguments to a view function, they need to be defined in the url, not the request payload. With that in mind, here's how you can refactor your code:

```
import json

@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def send_push_message(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    token =  data.get('token')
    title = data.get('title')
    message = data.get('message')
    extra = data.get('extra')
```